# Azure Website Git deployment with 3rd party libs not in nuget

Tags: azure-web-app-service, kudu, azure-git-deployment

I would like to use Azure git deployment with a product I am working on. We reference a 3rd party library which is privately supplied and not available on Nuget.

Azure syncs with the git repo as you would expect, but when it compiles it fails with errors saying it is unable to find the types within the 3rd party library.

The library is checked in to git in the bin folder.

How can I get Azure to reference this library when compiling?

Answer (score 1):

There should be nothing special about doing this on Azure Web Apps vs doing it locally. If your assembly is committed and you reference it from its committed location, everything should just work.

If it doesn't, please try running through the steps in [this document](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Make-sure-site-correctly-deploys-locally) to help identify the issue.

Comment: Thanks David for commenting, the work you guys have done here is fantastic. I suspect what you're saying is right, I expect the reference isn't pointing into bin but elsewhere on the FS. I'll check it when I'm back online and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use standard NuGet practices to make this work. Looking at the documentation for [Package Sources](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-settings) you just need to add the package source (like [myget.org](http://myget.org/)) to the nuget.config file place this at the same level as you *.sln file.

Comment: I missed the line where you said it was checked into source control. I agree with @DavidEbbo, it may not be referenced properly.